# Erase substring followed by a digit or character in C++ CLI

Tags: string, c++-cli

I have a few strings as follows:

```
First_1
First_2
Second_2
Third3
Fourth_A4
Fifth3B
Sixth2
Seventh_2A
Eighth
```

From the string, I need to get only the following `First`, `Second`,`Third`, `Fourth` and so on. That is, on the occurrence of an underscore or digit, ignore the rest of the string after the underscore or digit.

For removing the numbers, I have done this:

```
str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), std::isdigit), str.end());
```

and for characters, I have done this:

```
std::string wService::removeCharacters(std::string str, char chars[])
{   
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(chars); ++i)
    {
        str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), chars[i]), str.end());
    }
    return str;
}
```

But both the above methods, only remove the characters or the digits but I would like to obtain the first part of the string and remove the string followed by digits or characters. Which way would be better to do this?

Comment: A regex - https://ideone.com/DHItCG, or https://ideone.com/dXH0Yq

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, this regex doesn't work for strings such as Third3 and Sixth2. Even for these strings I should be able to get Third and Sixth respectively.

Comment: @smyslov, WiktorStribiżew's solution works perfectly: https://ideone.com/e8jpB7

Comment: The `^[a-zA-Z]+` regex gets a chunk of ASCII letters from the start of the string. That is why I think it should work for you provided your sample input list is fully representative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++-CLI, you can use a simple `^[A-Za-z]+` regex to match any one or more ASCII letters at the beginning of the string:

```
String ^ str = "Third3";
String ^ what = "^[A-Za-z]+";
String ^ result;
Regex ^ r = gcnew Regex(what, System::Text::RegularExpressions::RegexOptions::CultureInvariant);
result = r->Match(str)->Value;
Console::WriteLine(result); // => Third
```

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:** Question was re-tagged as C++-CLI; code below works with standard C++.

---

You can use `std::find_if` to find the first digit or underline, and delete from there:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

bool is_digit_or_underline(char x) {
    return std::isdigit(x) || (x == '_');
}

void remove_after_digit_or_underline(std::string &x) {
    x.erase(std::find_if(x.begin(), x.end(), is_digit_or_underline), x.end());
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    v.push_back("First_1");
    v.push_back("First_2");
    v.push_back("Second_2");
    v.push_back("Third3");
    v.push_back("Fourth_A4");
    v.push_back("Fifth3B");
    v.push_back("Sixth2");
    v.push_back("Seventh_2A");
    v.push_back("Eighth");

    for (size_t i=0; i<v.size(); ++i) {
        remove_after_digit_or_underline(v[i]);
        std::cout << v[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
First
First
Second
Third
Fourth
Fifth
Sixth
Seventh
Eighth
```

Comment: Does is_digit_or_underline function accept a string or a char?

Comment: See the code: it takes a `char`. `find_if` will search all of the container (in this case, string) for the first element (in this case, `char`) for which the function returns true.

Comment: when I use the code above, I get the following error at the place where is_digit_or_underline called in the find_if. `a pointer to member is not valid for a managed class`

Comment: Works fine for me: https://ideone.com/7XBmas. From the error message, I'm guessing that you are using Managed C++? In this case, it might be a good idea to tag the question `c++-cli`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
{
    if (!std::isalpha(str[i]))
    {
        str.erase(i, str.size() - i);
        break;
    }
}
```